# Google Cloud OCR for both printed and handwritten data

Tags: python, json, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, ocr

I am using Google Cloud OCR for reading text from images of printed documents (currently), which uses the client.text_detection() attribute. However, I want to modify the model so it can recognize both handwritten and printed text. The handwritten part needs the client.document_text_detection() attribute. How do I combine the two?

Comment: I tried this last year, just to recognize hand written only and had almost no success.  Please post if you've had better luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have just to use DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION.

For example, check [this image](https://s16458.pcdn.co/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/img_tp_4_13-1.png) I found in a Google Search, which has both printed and handrwritten text. I made a request to the Vision API specifying the feature DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION, and it successfully returned the printed text and the handwritten text (in bold):

"description": "http://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/fb/historical\nDate\n01/04.2017\n01/03/2017\n12/30/2016\n1229 2016\n12/28/2016\n1227/2016\n12/23/2016\n12/22/2016\n1221/2016\n12/20/2016\n12/19/2016\n1206 7016\n**12/20/2016**\nOpen\n117.55\n116.03\n116,595\n117\n118.19\n116.96\n117\n118.86\n118.92\n119.5\n119.85\n120.9\n**121,1**\nHigh\n119.66\n117.84\n116.83\n117.531\n118.25\n118.68\n117.56\n118.99\n119.2\n119.77\n120.36\n121.5\n**123.5**\nLow\n117.29\n115.51\n114.7739\n116.06\n116.65\n116.864\n116.3\n116.93\n118.48\n118.8\n118.51\n119.27\n**119.22**\nClose / Last\n118.69\n116.86\n115.05\n116.35\n116.92\n118.01\n117.27\n117.4\n119.04\n119.09\n119.24\n119.87\n**119.87**\nVolume\n19.594,560\n20.635,600\n18.668.290\n9,925,082\n11.985.740\n12,034,590\n10,885,030\n16.226,770\n10,747,610\n13,673,570\n15,871,360\n25,316,220\n**25,316, 220**\n",